# Rigorous definition of a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry

I was going through the following differential geometry lecture notes  :

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/III_M/differential_geometry.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjzw9PE-N3oAhVD8HMBHdLpCcgQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3sZC21Y0IRSt-prh6lAeJk

In the first page I came across the definition of a smooth function

It says that given a chart on $\ M $ with $ ( u,g) $ a  function at a point $ P$ , $f $ , defined from $\ g(u) $  to $\ R $ is smooth if  $\ f g^-1$  at  $\ u(p) $ in usual sense.

I got a bit confused here as the word smooth has been used to define a smooth funtion .

What is the defintion for smooth in usual sense ?

Comment: There is already a good definition of smooth in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see calculus).  This is used to define "smooth" in a general smooth manifold.  In $\mathbb{R}^n$ both definitions coincide.

Comment: Thanks a lot... was wondering to what extent differentiability is being granted

Answer (score 1):

A function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called smooth, if it is infinitely often differentiable. In parctice this means that all the partial derivatives and derivatives of derivatives exist.

Since a manifold is usually not a $\mathbb{R}^n$ vectorspace, it is not even defined what a (partial) derivative is (you need to be able to add elements and do scalar multiplication to define the deriviative). But manifolds locally "look like $\mathbb{R}^n$", this is formalized by charts that allow you to see a neighborhood of a point in the manifold as a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In your case, $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ and near the point you have a chart $\varphi \colon U \to \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (this is a bijection). So you can define $f \circ \varphi ^{-1} \colon \varphi(U) \to \mathbb{R}$. Here you can define partial derivatives and you can see whether $f \circ \varphi ^{-1}$ is smooth.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apologies for being a bit late in getting back. ..  I would need a little help in understanding how it helps in defining partial deriviatives..

Comment: I do not understand your question. A function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth if the derivative $f'$ and all the higher derivatives $f^{(n)}$ exist. If your function has multiple inputs, then you have to specify in which direction you take the derivative (this is called the partial derivatives). Example: $f(x,y)=2x^2+y$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=4x$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=1$. If all those (and higher ones exist), then the function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is called smooth.

Comment: My post does not explain how anything helps in defining partial derivatives. My post does explain how the partial derivatives explain when a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is called smooth. This then also helps explain, when a function $N \to M$ between manifolds $N,M$ is called smooth.

Comment: The question was inspired from a kind of interpolated continuation...sorry if I got it wrong..but I see in the second paragraph you had started  with "it is not even defined what a partial deriviative is ".  So , I thought that I have missed yhe point of how charts here are facilitating or helping in setting up a framework to define partial deriviatives .

Comment: The collection of partial derivatives is called the total derivative and it is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. To a differentiable function $f:N \to M$ (and a point $p  \in N$ you can associate a derivative $D_pf \colon T_pN \to T_{f(p)}M$ between tangentspaces $T_pN\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_{f(p)}M\cong\mathbb{R}^m$. For smooth maps between manifolds, there is no derivative that goes $N \to M$ (unlike smooth maps between vectorspaces).

Comment: Sorry for coming back a bit late.  I might not have gone as far the material required but I could not understand the last line that says unlike smooth maps between vector spaces there is no deriviative for manifolds that goes between N->M. Is it because the range set of the deriviatives in case of manifolds might not be a vector space ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct